# DBA_AUTOTASK_SCHEDULE incorrect?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

can you please help me understand whether I run into an Oracle defect here or whether I misunderstand this. My version (on AWS):

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production    0
PL/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production  0
TNS for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production  0
NLSRTL Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production  0
```

dba_autotask_window_clients states that my work day windows start at **04:00 UTC+2**:

```
SELECT window_name,WINDOW_NEXT_TIME,WINDOW_NEXT_TIME at time zone '+02:00'  
FROM dba_autotask_window_clients c order by WINDOW_NEXT_TIME asc;

WINDOW_NAME.....WINDOW_NEXT_TIME........................WINDOW_NEXT_TIMEATTIMEZONE'+02:00'
THURSDAY_WINDOW 26.SEP.2019 22:00:00,000000000 EST5EDT  27.SEP.2019 04:00:00,000000000 +02:00
FRIDAY_WINDOW   27.SEP.2019 22:00:00,000000000 EST5EDT  28.SEP.2019 04:00:00,000000000 +02:00
SATURDAY_WINDOW 28.SEP.2019 06:00:00,000000000 EST5EDT  28.SEP.2019 12:00:00,000000000 +02:00
SUNDAY_WINDOW   29.SEP.2019 06:00:00,000000000 EST5EDT  29.SEP.2019 12:00:00,000000000 +02:00
MONDAY_WINDOW   30.SEP.2019 22:00:00,000000000 EST5EDT  01.OCT.2019 04:00:00,000000000 +02:00
TUESDAY_WINDOW  01.OCT.2019 22:00:00,000000000 EST5EDT  02.OCT.2019 04:00:00,000000000 +02:00
WEDNESDAY_WINDOW02.OCT.2019 22:00:00,000000000 EST5EDT  03.OCT.2019 04:00:00,000000000 +02:00
```

dba_autotask_window_history confirms the start time at **04:00 UTC+2**

```
select WINDOW_NAME, WINDOW_START_TIME,WINDOW_START_TIME at time zone '+02:00', WINDOW_END_TIME,WINDOW_END_TIME at time zone '+02:00'  
from dba_autotask_window_history order by WINDOW_START_TIME desc;

WINDOW_NAME.........WINDOW_START_TIME...................WINDOW_START_TIMEATTIMEZONE'+02:00'.....WINDOW_END_TIME.....................WINDOW_END_TIMEATTIMEZONE'+02:00'
WEDNESDAY_WINDOW    26.SEP.2019 02:00:00,313275000 GMT  26.SEP.2019 04:00:00,313275000 +02:00   26.SEP.2019 06:00:00,311376000 GMT  26.SEP.2019 08:00:00,311376000 +02:00
TUESDAY_WINDOW      25.SEP.2019 02:00:00,406224000 GMT  25.SEP.2019 04:00:00,406224000 +02:00   25.SEP.2019 06:00:00,344330000 GMT  25.SEP.2019 08:00:00,344330000 +02:00
MONDAY_WINDOW       24.SEP.2019 02:00:00,321340000 GMT  24.SEP.2019 04:00:00,321340000 +02:00   24.SEP.2019 06:00:00,083366000 GMT  24.SEP.2019 08:00:00,083366000 +02:00
SUNDAY_WINDOW       22.SEP.2019 10:00:00,209382000 GMT  22.SEP.2019 12:00:00,209382000 +02:00   23.SEP.2019 06:00:00,296056000 GMT  23.SEP.2019 08:00:00,296056000 +02:00
[...]
```

and yet, DBA_AUTOTASK_SCHEDULE says the start_time is **22:00 UTC+2** - **How can this be correct? This should say 04:00 UTC+2 as well, shouldn't it?**

```
select WINDOW_NAME, START_TIME,START_TIME at time zone '+02:00', DURATION
 from DBA_AUTOTASK_SCHEDULE order by start_time asc;

WINDOW_NAME.....START_TIME......................................START_TIMEATTIMEZONE'+02:00'............DURATION
THURSDAY_WINDOW 26.SEP.2019 22:00:00,100531000 EUROPE/BERLIN    26.SEP.2019 22:00:00,100531000 +02:00   +00 04:00:00.000000
FRIDAY_WINDOW   27.SEP.2019 22:00:00,100531000 EUROPE/BERLIN    27.SEP.2019 22:00:00,100531000 +02:00   +00 04:00:00.000000
SATURDAY_WINDOW 28.SEP.2019 06:00:00,100531000 EUROPE/BERLIN    28.SEP.2019 06:00:00,100531000 +02:00   +00 20:00:00.000000
SUNDAY_WINDOW   29.SEP.2019 06:00:00,100531000 EUROPE/BERLIN    29.SEP.2019 06:00:00,100531000 +02:00   +00 20:00:00.000000
MONDAY_WINDOW   30.SEP.2019 22:00:00,100531000 EUROPE/BERLIN    30.SEP.2019 22:00:00,100531000 +02:00   +00 04:00:00.000000
TUESDAY_WINDOW  01.OCT.2019 22:00:00,100531000 EUROPE/BERLIN    01.OCT.2019 22:00:00,100531000 +02:00   +00 04:00:00.000000
WEDNESDAY_WINDOW02.OCT.2019 22:00:00,100531000 EUROPE/BERLIN    02.OCT.2019 22:00:00,100531000 +02:00   +00 04:00:00.000000
```

Comment: In order to consider time zones and daylight saving times have a look at [Repeat Intervals and Daylight Savings](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/scheduse.htm#ADMIN10020) and [Start Dates and Repeat Intervals](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72266), esp. item *When start_date is NULL, the Scheduler determines the time zone for the repeat interval as follows...*

Comment: hi @WernfriedDomscheit yes, the windows were created with start_date NULL. but how does this explain that DBA_AUTOTASK_SCHEDULE shows times different from the other two views (dba_autotask_window_history  and dba_autotask_window_clients)? Isn't this still a bug? ty peter